# Setting install path with ZXPSignCmd and Adobe HTML Panels

Tags: html, adobe, exchange-server, panels, cc

I am signing an extension with ZXPSignCmd. At the end I have a signed .zxp file. The problem is that I can't force exchange manager to install the extension in appropriate folder. With exchange packager I would set the install directory to $adobecommon/CEP/extensions but I can't seem to do this with ZXPSignCmd.

Am I missing a flag?

Answer (score 0):

The .zxp is kind of like a proprietary zip format.  If you use a tool like The Unarchiver (http://unarchiver.c3.cx/unarchiver) you can unzip the ZXP and the result will be a panel folder.  This folder can be put into the CEP/extensions folder and then is accessible in Photoshop > Window > Extensions

Answer (score 0):

adobe zxp installer automatically install it to ~common files\Adobe\CEP\extensions http://zxpinstaller.com/ download it from here .
If you want to do it manually simply rename your .zxp as zip extract it in folder and paste it to ..\program files(x86)\common files\Adobe\CEP\extensions